# how to query where multiple many to many relations are involved

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have few tables with the following relationships:-

```
publications->id name  
categories->id name
types->id name
program->id name
```

A publication can have many categories, many types and many programs .. Similarly each one has many publications. So the publication table has many to many relation with each of these tables.
Thus I created associate tables for each of them and put up the below three tables to link each of the above

```
pub_cat ->publicationid categoryid
pub_type->publicationid typeid
pub_prog->publicationid programid
```

Now I have to find the name of all publications where say categoryid=2,typeid=2 and programid=1

I am quite new with these complex queries and any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just solved this ..thanks @eggyal,@raphael

```
select id,title,pub_cat.catid,pub_prog.progid,pub_type.typeid from publications
inner join pub_cat on publications.id=pub_cat.pubid
inner join pub_prog on publications.id=pub_prog.pubid inner join pub_type
on publications.id=pub_type.pubid where pub_type.typeid=6 and pub_cat.catid=7
and pub_prog.progid=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at joins you join all the tables together and state in the where clause what you want to find. An example could be:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
             ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
WHERE t2.a = 1;
```

this is just an example from here [MySQL Refeerence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)